# I can't transfer large file from ubuntu hard drive to windows hd?

Tags: transfer

The file is 26gb and ubuntu and it seems ubuntu can't do ANYTHING with it. Try to drag and drop, computer  freezes. Try to split it into smaller pieces via gnome, computer freezes. I have 4gb of ram. Is it impossible?  My windows hd is formatted at NTSF and the ubuntu one is ext3.

Comment: NTFS, not NTSF. Also why are you using ext3? Ubuntu should use ext4.

Comment: Im not sure, honestly

Comment: Did you upgrade from an older Ubuntu release? Did you choose ext3 in "Something else" during installation? It should be ext4.

Comment: Well it says ext3/ext4

Comment: What says ext3/ext4?

Comment: I don't think ext3 or 4 makes a difference. What do you mean by "freezing"? It can slow it a lot, and with a good disk you can expect a 10-12 minutes time for the copy... are you waiting enough? See also http://superuser.com/a/70585/259955 and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107703/why-is-my-pc-freezing-while-im-copying-a-file-to-a-pendrive

Comment: @Rmano ext3 metadata is larger than ext4 metadata.

Comment: @Jash open 2 tty's. Start "top" in one and use command line to copy the file over with the other. Watch for top to show what is filling up. Maybe your swap is too low? Maybe memory is a bottleneck.

Comment: what version ntfs-3g are you using?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried booting up from an install disk, selecting "try ubuntu" and then copying the file over, as it could be that ubuntu is using the file/ permission issues

it could also be that windows hasn't completely unmounted the partition as it is in sleep mode etc. (windows 8+ I think)

you may also want to put ext4 on there for the future

Comment: I will try from your first suggestion,  thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

May be the file manager installed on your ubuntu system is causing the problem. The default file manager of ubuntu (unity) is nautilus. I will advice you to install another file manager. You can try PCManFm or Thunar. Just open the terminal and type these code:

to install PCManFM try this code,

> sudo apt-get install pcmanfm

to install Thunar try this code,

> sudo apt-get install thunar

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: If that is the case command line should be the option to go for ;-) (it will have the lease overhead)